# Neural network for text generation - Reverse summarizer (Python / Keras)

Tags: python, keras, nlp

I am about to start working on a neural network for text generation. Inputs will be some words from a user (e.g. Brexit vote tomorrow chance of UK staying within EU slim) and the output will be a nice, well-written sentence (e.g. The Brexit vote will take place tomorrow and the UK is unlikely to stay within the European Union).

For the implementation, I am thinking about a sequence2sequence model but, before starting to code, I would like to check whether this subject has not been addressed before. After many Google searches, it seems that nobody has done a similar project before (although there's a lot of papers about text translation), which surprises me because such a tool would be useful for many people, such as journalists, etc.

Has any of you seen some useful Python code or relevant articles somewhere?

Comment: Sorry but asking for algorithm recommendations and articles is off-topic on SO, interesting as this is. I see various hits when searching on "text generation [using Keras/etc.]".

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that. Any forum you would recommend? I did a similar Google search than yours and all the entries are about random text generation, e.g. writing nonsensical text like JK Rowling or Game of Thrones...

Comment: Perhaps "reverse summarization/text generation of journalistic articles"...?

Answer (score 1):

Sequence2Sequence is what comes to my mind. Text generation code using RNN/LSTM just creates grammatically correct but meaningless sentences as you discovered via Google.

Do you have a large corpus of examples to train a seq2seq model? Translation models require very large corpus. One option for creating such a corpus could be to gather headlines and first paragraphs of news articles. Treat headlines as original language and first paragraph/sentences of the article as the language to translate into.

Here's a [blog](https://medium.com/@david.campion/text-generation-using-bidirectional-lstm-and-doc2vec-models-1-3-8979eb65cb3a) about using a second model using Doc2Vec to filter the sentences generated from seq2seq